# JQuery HTML Div Navigation

Tags: jquery, html

The folowing code shows my `div` implementation for a side menu.

```
<div class="top_link">
    <h3><a href="/dashboard/" class="dash_board_link">Dashboard</a></h3>
</div>
<div id="accordion" class="accordion_menu">
    <h3><a href="#section1">Hits</a></h3>
    <div class="content">
        <a href="/dailyhits/">Daily Hits</a>
        <a href="/tophundredurls/?page=1">Top 100 URL</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="bottom_link">
    <h3><a href="/userwatchlist">Watch Lists</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="bottom_link">
    <h3><a href="/twitterinsights">Twitter Insights</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="bottom_link selected">
    <h3><a href="/managedomain"> Manage Domain </a></h3>
</div>
```

Using jQuery I want to read the current URL and trim it to the format which is specified in the `href` attribute and if there's match I want to add the selected part of the particular `div` element to the `div class="xxx select"`. In order to do this I added the following jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var pathname = window.location.pathname;
});
```

I dont know how to proceed further because um so new to jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Haven't tried it yet but, something along these lings should work:

```
var pathname = window.location.pathname;
var pathPart = pathname.slice('.com/', '/'); // assuming this is the end of your url
$('#navigation a').click(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#navigation a').removeClass('active');
    if ( pathPart == url ) {
        $(this).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: One note of caution though - in ie (up to version 8 I think) the href attribute includes the full url, including host, even if it's not what you type in/set using jQuery. Accounting for this can be tricky (although recent releases of jQuery might have taken care of it). You should probably do some kind of feature detection in your init scripts (create a dummy hidden link, set its url to "/" and then check if the url returned by .attr("href") is equal to "/" or not)

Answer (score 2):

Using jquery basically involves selecting something on the screen (for example a div) and then performing an action on it (eg replacing its text).

So your jquery needs to do something with the pathname var you've set up.

Also your jquery isn't quite valid as your missing a couple of characters from the end:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  var pathname = window.location.pathname; 
  // select something here and use the pathname, eg:
  $(".bottom_link").append(pathname);
});
```

But from your description I'm not really sure what you want to select or what you want to do with it - but hopefully this will get you started?

Comment: okay in every div element there is an <a href> element . i want to do traverse kind of a thing to match the current url's value with ahref inside value . Thank you